# wget - N always redownloads file even if timestemp does not change

Tags: linux, bash, wget

I found this site on how to download files, of which the timestamp did change:

https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Time_002dStamping-Usage.html

I tried it out but wget always keeps on redownloading it. But the timestamp does not change. What do I not get here?

```
[tom@machine Downloads]$ ll
total 48536
-rw-r--r-- 1 tom students 49693179 Apr  5 07:22 assembly_summary_genbank.txt
[tom@machine Downloads]$ wget -N ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/genbank/assembly_summary_genbank.txt
--2018-04-05 18:24:42--  ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/genbank/assembly_summary_genbank.txt
           => ‘.listing’
Resolving ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov (ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov)... 165.112.9.229, 2607:f220:41e:250::11
Connecting to ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov (ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov)|165.112.9.229|:21... connected.
Logging in as anonymous ... Logged in!
==> SYST ... done.    ==> PWD ... done.
==> TYPE I ... done.  ==> CWD (1) /genomes/genbank ... done.
==> PASV ... done.    ==> LIST ... done.

.listing                                                 [ <=>                                                                                                                  ]   1.11K  --.-KB/s    in 0.002s  

2018-04-05 18:24:44 (449 KB/s) - ‘.listing’ saved [1133]

Removed ‘.listing’.
--2018-04-05 18:24:44--  ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/genbank/assembly_summary_genbank.txt
           => ‘assembly_summary_genbank.txt’
==> CWD not required.
==> SIZE assembly_summary_genbank.txt ... 49693179
==> PASV ... done.    ==> RETR assembly_summary_genbank.txt ... done.
Length: 49693179 (47M) (unauthoritative)

assembly_summary_genbank.txt                         100%[=====================================================================================================================>]  47.39M  5.44MB/s    in 9.1s    

2018-04-05 18:24:54 (5.20 MB/s) - ‘assembly_summary_genbank.txt’ saved [49693179]

[tom@machine Downloads]$ ll
total 48536
-rw-r--r-- 1 tom students 49693179 Apr  5 07:22 assembly_summary_genbank.txt
```

Comment: The date stamps in an ftp listing both have a non standard format ( or may not be there at all ), and tend to be rather imprecise.  I think you need to use http for this to work.

Comment: That file link provides no response headers as far as I can tell so `wget -N` is err'ing on the side of caution and just re-downloading since no timestamp is available.